# Basic Authentification to get json

Tags: php, json, authentication

I’m getting a json file with this little piece of code.

```
    $json = file_get_contents('https://someticketingservice.com/jsonfileandaguments');
```

But I need to use basic authentication to access the file i readed the simple auth manual. But I can't figure out how it work and since i want to hard-code the credentials it's not very clear for me.

Comment: f_g_c just does basic http requests by default. if you need authentication (http basic, cookie-based, whatever), you'll have to use more complicated methods. a PHP stream, or cURL.

Comment: If you want, REALLY super basic Auth you could either use login like user:password@domain.com or include it as $_GET variables and pass them

Comment: And i guess if i get  "failed to open stream: " than i will need a PHP stream or Curl ?